При добавлении картинки в pygame меняется цветовая гамма python

фон должен быть как на этой картинке, но по факту он получается такой, что стволы деревьев и земля - синие, а зеленый меняет оттенок на другой
import pygame #1 часть кода
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1920,1200))
pygame.display.set_caption('Name')
icon=pygame.image.load('images/icon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
bg_old=pygame.image.load('images/bg.jpg')
bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg_old, (1920,1200))
while running:
    screen.blit(bg, (bg_x,0))
    screen.blit(bg, (bg_x+1920,0))
    screen.blit(walk_right[player_anim_count], (800,670))
    update_animation() #gpt
    pygame.display.update()
    bg_x -=10
    if bg_x <=-1920:
        bg_x=0

